# How to control node names in xml using Request.CreateResponse?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am using asp.net web api and eventhough I personally like to handle my data in json by using `HttpResponseMessage` and `Request.CreateResponse` I can let the client decide what they rather work in.

However when looking at the xml data I see the node names are horrible. I am wondering can they be changed other than changing file names? I tried xmlRoot for instance but that did nothing.

For instance I do a return like this

```
return Request.CreateResponse<ResponseResult<List<PersonSearchDto>>>(HttpStatusCode.OK, p);
```

I get a root node named like this

```
ResponseResultOfArrayOfPersonSearchK0AojvId
```

Would be nice if I could rename to something like `Persons`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right way to solve your problem is to use the CollectionDataContractAttribute:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.collectiondatacontractattribute.aspx

So in your case, you could have a type like this:

```
[CollectionDataContract(Name = "Persons")]
public class PersonResults : List<PersonSearchDto>
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in your `Global.asax.cs`:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlDataContractSerializer = true;
```

And then decorate your classes and properties using `[DataMember]` and `[DataContract]` as explained in [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733127.aspx):

```
namespace MyTypes
{
    [DataContract]
    public class PurchaseOrder
    {
        private int poId_value;

        // Apply the DataMemberAttribute to the property.
        [DataMember]
        public int PurchaseOrderId
        {

            get { return poId_value; }
            set { poId_value = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure why you got voted down......Intelligent wont' give me the namespace to import in. Is this only for wcf? I am using the asp.net web api.

Comment: Works for Web API ... you need to add a reference to `System.Runtime.Serialization.dll`.

Comment: Also, specifically you can use `[DataContract(Name="Persons")]` in your example.

Comment: Ok I can try that. Question though this wont' turn all requests to always send back xml right?

Comment: No, if the client requests JSON, it will still return JSON, however if it requests XML, it will now use the `XmlDataContractSerializer`.

Comment: Finally have gotten time to try this. "GlobalConfiguration.Config.Formatters.XmlDataContractSerializer = true;" does not exist do I need to import something?